# Typescript convert type `typeof Foo` to `Foo`

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm working on a generic Typescript interface where a factory class is instantiated with a particular class and has methods responsible for creating various instances of that class.  My ideal type interface, which I cannot seem to achieve, is as follows:

```
class BaseModel { /* impl */ }
class Foo extends BaseModel { /* impl */ }
class Factory<T extends BaseModel> { /* impl */ }

let factory : Factory<Foo> = new Factory(Foo)
let fooInstance = factory.build() // returns type: `Foo`
```

However I cannot figure out how to get a declaration of `Factory<T>` to achieve this without either compromising the return type or maintaining a parallel constructor type definition.

If I rely on nothing but the types given by the classes I've declared, the return type of the build function is always `BaseClass`, plus I have to make the generic `Factory<typeof Foo>` instead of `Factory<Foo>`:

```
class BaseModel {
  static classMethod() : string {
    return 'i am class method'
  }

  hello() {
    return 'hello world'
  }
}
class Foo extends BaseModel {}

class Factory<T extends typeof BaseModel> {
  private _modelClass : T

  constructor(modelClass : T) {
    this._modelClass = modelClass
  }

  build() {
    return new this._modelClass()
  }

  echoClassMethod() {
    console.log(this._modelClass.classMethod())
  }
}

let factory : Factory<typeof Foo> = new Factory(Foo)
let fooInstance = factory.build() // Returns type `BaseClass` instead of `Foo`
```

But if I want the factory type interface to work correctly, I have to maintain a parallel type definition that mirrors `typeof BaseModel`, but as a constructor function instead:

```
class BaseModel {
  static classMethod() : string {
    return 'i am class method'
  }

  hello() {
    return 'hello world'
  }
}
class Foo extends BaseModel {}

// Have to maintain a separate type that 
// mirrors the class interface of my target class
type BaseModelConstructor<T extends BaseModel> = {
  new(...args: any[]) : T 
  classMethod() : string
}

class Factory<T extends BaseModel> {
  private _modelClass : BaseModelConstructor<T>

  constructor(modelClass : BaseModelConstructor<T>) {
    this._modelClass = modelClass
  }

  build() {
    return new this._modelClass()
  }

  echoClassMethod() {
    console.log(this._modelClass.classMethod())
  }
}

let factory : Factory<Foo> = new Factory(Foo)
let fooInstance = factory.build() // Correctly returns type `Foo`
```

There has to be a better way to convert a `typeof X` into an `X` or vice versa?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming `X` is the both the name of a constructor value and the name of the
instance type (which is what happens when you declare  `class X {...}`):

---

UPDATE:

As of TypeScript 2.8, there is a [predefined type function](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v2.8.0/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1388-L1391) called `InstanceType<>` which takes the type of a class constructor and evaluates to the type of its instance, using [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) instead of a lookup.  So you can now get from `typeof X` to `X` by using `InstanceType<typeof X>`.  But `(typeof X)['prototype']` below still works.

---

To get from `typeof X` to `X`, you can usually [lookup](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#keyof-and-lookup-types) the `prototype` property of the `typeof X` constructor type.  For example, in the following I've annotated the return type of `build()` to be `T['prototype']`:

```
class Factory<T extends typeof BaseModel> {
  private _modelClass : T

  constructor(modelClass : T) {
    this._modelClass = modelClass
  }

  // note the declared return type
  build(): T['prototype'] {
    return new this._modelClass()
  }

  echoClassMethod() {
    console.log(this._modelClass.classMethod())
  }
}
```

And then the following works:

```
let factory = new Factory(Foo)
let fooInstance = factory.build() // Foo, as desired.
```

Does that help?  Good luck!

Comment: This is very helpful and takes care of my problems perfectly.  For type simplicity I ended up adding a second generic with a default:

`class Factory<T extends typeof BaseModel, M extends BaseModel=T['prototype'>`

Wasn't previously aware you could reference types of members in this way. Should help cleanup some of my other typings code.